# Can we add new node in running blockchain network developed using Hypeledger?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, blockchain

Can we add new node in running blockchain network developed using Hyperledger?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question the right way, the answer is: Yes

Just in case you want to **add a new Organization** into a running network, you can 
follow [this tutorial](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/channel_update_tutorial.html#adding-an-org-to-a-channel).

Briefly, It's 5 steps:

- Step 1: Prepare new Organization's configuration files (*new-org-crypto.yaml* and *configtx.yaml*, which contains only the config of the new Organization).
- Step 2: Generate crypto materials for new organization base on the configuration file.
- Step 3: Update channel configuration to let the existing components know about the new organization.
- Step 4: Create a docker compose file and then kick off the containers
- Step 5: Join peers into the channel.
- Additional step: install & update chain code to let these new peers become endorsing peers.

If you mean to add **a new peer** into an existing network, It will be simpler ([follow this](https://medium.com/@wahabjawed/extending-hyperledger-fabric-network-adding-a-new-peer-4f52f70a7217)):

- Step 1: Generate crypto material for new peer by editing *crypto-config.yaml* file and use *cryptogen* tool with *extend* command.
- Step 2: Create a docker compose file and then kick off the containers.
- Step 3: Join the new peer into the channel.

Hope this help!