# Error : No MSP found able to do that while adding a new org to a network

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I have added a new peer to an existing fabric network but I keep on getting following error on the peer of new org. The other orgs' peers say that the new peer is non responsive.

Unable to extract msp.Identity from peer Identity: Peer Identity [0a 0e 43 61 70 69 74 61 6c 43 69 74 79 4d 53 50 12 b6 06 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 42 45 ..........3d 0a 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 45 4e 44 20 43 45 52 54 49 46 49 43 41 54 45 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 0a] cannot be validated. No MSP found able to do that." grpc.code=Unknown grpc.call_duration=2.9251ms

I am unable to understand what's the issue here. How is MSP not available to peer or new Org. I have went through docs and google and atlast I count on stackoverflow. Thanks people for helping me out.

Comment: You should describe more detail about your scenario and where did you get the error.

I have a comment about adding new peers into an existing network (https://stackoverflow.com/a/55018424/7572711).
 If this can't help, feel comfortable to leave more information about your problem

Comment: I think that simply generating the crypto and anchorPeer.tx and then issuing join command won't work as the genesis of the channel has already been on the blockchain. I fetched the config_block of the channel, added new channels config to it, computed the update delta using configtxlator and the wrapped up everything into an envelope and got it signed with all the orgs in the channel. Now I issued an update channel command. All the orgs discovered the new org, sent it a request, but then on the new org, I see the above error occurs and it's stuck and hence non-responsive.

Answer (score 6):

> The other orgs' peers say that the new peer is non responsive.

You need to make sure that both peers (on both organizations) have joined the channel (via "peer channel join" or the SDK equivalent call).

Comment: Thanks for this.   I only had the anchor peers joining the channel.